# Custom cell is not correctly drawn when a row is inserted using insertRows(atPaths) method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom cell, which is subclass of `UITableViewCell`, call it `Cell`.

I have added a `UITableViewCell` through a storyboard to a tableview ( tableview's content is set to Dynamic Prototypes) and have set cells class to `Cell`. Also I have set the reuse identifier appropriately.

The cell is defined in `xib`, and I load it like this:

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "Cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")
```

The cell itself has only two elements, and those are, one container view (a `UIView`) and one image view (a `UIImageView`).

Both of those elements are connected through outlets to the `Cell`.

These two elements are positioned in a `xib` using the `Autolayout` constraints. Also, before the cell is about to display, I do something like this in my `ViewController` (tried both `cellForRowAtPath` and `willDisplayCellForRowAtPath` methods):

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.layer.frame.height / 2.0
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
cell.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.containerView.layer.frame.height / 2.0
cell.containerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
cell.containerView.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

and in both cases, at the time when I call `UITableView's insertRows(atIndexPaths)` method, the cell is inserted, but it is not displayed properly. The next time, i insert new row (cell), the previous one is drawn correctly...And so on...

Here is how I insert cells (on a button click event):

```
func addCell(_ title: String) {
    titles.append(title)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: messages.count - 1, section: 0)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .bottom)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true) 
}
```

So, how to have a cell drawn correctly in this case?

Comment: The `cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.layer....` is worrying. To what is the right hand side `imageView` referring? In answer to your question for fixed height cells `cellForRowAt` is a fine place to do this, but I wonder what `cell.imageView.layer.frame.height` value is. Even better, the very best place for adjusting rounding is in the [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) of your cell's subclass.

Comment: @Rob I’ll print values once again (when I get my hands on computer), to double-check the values. I did that already in controller’s willDisplayCell forRowAtPath method. Values seemed fine when it comes to sizes, but I forgot to check the value of frames (their origins).The code I have posted, was originally in overriden `layoutSubviews()` method of my cell.

Comment: @Rob About your questions... `imageView` is referring to `cell.imageView`. It was a typo. Also, my cells don’t have fixed height...

Comment: It's quite possible that when `layoutSubviews`, the image view's height is something like zero or whatever size was originally set in the NIB. So you might want to reference the size of the `cell`. (Or, you can subclass `UIImageView` and have its `layoutSubviews` do the rounding, which might be more hassle than its worth.) When you look at the `frame` of the image view in `layoutSubviews`, you'll see precisely what I'm talking about.

Comment: Rob You were right. The values used in layoutSubviews are the values that are originally set in the nib file. Also, as proposed as a solution by [mikeytdan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/831344/mikeytdan),the issue disappeared after wrapping the rounding code in DispatchQueue.main.async {} (Just for the note,I am not doing anything on a background thread).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most elegant way of handling this is to subclass `UIImageView`:

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedImageView: UIImageView {

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let radius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
    }

}
```

Then use this `RoundedImageView` instead of `UIImageView`, and you'll automatically get this rounding, regardless of how the image view is resized dynamically by the auto layout engine. No manual tweaking of the radius is needed elsewhere.

And, if you want, by making it `@IBDesignable`, if you put this in a separate "framework" target in your app (which we do so IB doesn't need to compile the whole project in order to render the `@IBDesignable` target), you can also specify this as the base class for an image view in Interface Builder, and it will be rendered dynamically right in IB, too:

[image]

The above was a top level view in the scene, but it works the same if it's in a cell prototype or wherever. Just set the base class for the image view. Obviously, make sure you have "Clip to Bounds" selected on the "Attributes" inspector in IB, too.

By the way, you don’t have to make this designable if you don’t want to see the effect in IB, but you can if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Talked with you about this outside of StackOverflow, posting it here for others benefit.

I created a demo project that has the same issue you mentioned. I found a workaround by subclassing the cell and overriding layoutSubviews and setting the `cornerRadius` using `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`:

```
class TestCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var colorImageView: UIImageView!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.colorImageView.layer.cornerRadius = min(self.colorImageView.frame.width, self.colorImageView.frame.height) / 2
        }
    }

}
```

Another workaround I found was by using an observer(Swift 4) and a `layoutIfNeeded()` call before setting the `cornerRadius`

```
class TestCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var colorImageView: UIImageView!

    var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        observer = self.observe(\.frame) { (cell, change) in
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.colorImageView.layer.cornerRadius = min(self.colorImageView.frame.width, self.colorImageView.frame.height) / 2
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Rob's answer is a good route to go. Leaving this here in case this solution helps anyone out with a different issue.