# UIImageView circular shape swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I used this code to make UIImageView in a custom UITableViewCell, but the circular shape isn't updated until i pressed on the table cell, I tried the code in both awakeFromNib() and  layoutSubviews()

```
  userImage.layer.cornerRadius = userImage.frame.size.width / 2
  userImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
  userImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
  userImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

Comment: add `userImage.clipToBounds = true`

Comment: [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) is definitely the right place to do this. Not `awakeFromNib`. The best place to do this is in a `UIImageView` subclass (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46530486/1271826). Then, whenever you need circular image view, just use this subclass, and you get the desired behavior with no extra code.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to override the [`layoutSubviews()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) method of your UITableViewCell subclass, as it will be called on drawing updates.

Then just set your UIImageView's cornerRadius as you like:

```
class MyCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    private let circularImageView: UIImageView = {
        $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        $0.layer.masksToBounds = true
        $0.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
        return $0
    }(UIImageView())

    // ...

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        circularImageView.layer.cornerRadius = circularImageView.frame.size.width/2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you create you tableviewCell programmatically you have to override init

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle,   reuseIdentifier: String?) {
super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier:  reuseIdentifier)
//put your code here
}
```

Answer (score -2):

update the imageViews cornerRadius just after a little time. Because frame.size.width / 2 will be different at runtime :

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline : .now() + 0.05 {
  self.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = userImage.frame.size.width / 2
  self.userImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
  self.userImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
  self.userImage.layer.borderWidth = 1

}
```

Comment: Using an arbitrary delay is not advisable. You risk having a flicker as the corner radius is applied (or missing it altogether). The [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) is designed for this use-case.

Comment: no there won't be any flicker. you can not see 0.05 second with eye. I have tried this a lot of apps and it works good. Maybe not the best option but straightforward solution. deserves to be downvoted but this works without any problem